# Data Source from UDL. OraOLEDB

Tags: ssis, oledb

Is there any way that an SSIS Data Source will be getting the connection from UDL file?
I have a UDL working perfect by connecting to a server but the provider isn't available on the list that the SSIS new connection window is showing me

my udl: Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Data Source=my_db

The list of providers in SSIS:
[image: The list of providers in SSIS]

i also tried by using ODBC that will be connecting to the same server. The ODBC test connection succeeded but when i try to use in ssis connection manager i get the following error:
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Properties by right clicking on your SSIS Project from Solution Explorer Pane. **`Set Run64BitRuntime = False`** under Configuration Properties --> Debugging.